# Android Fragments and TelephonyManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, telephonymanager, android-music-player

I have a question, I am using a class that extends Fragments to play music through MusicPlayer, within this class this using PhoneStateListener and TelephonyManager to pause the music if a call comes in, everything ok, doubt that have is that when I start the application, the song starts automatically and would like to avoid that, any suggestions ?? here part of my code:

PS: Sorry for my bad english

```
public class FragmentPlaySong extends Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play_song, container, false);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    ...
    ...

    //Service MediaPlayer pause when Incoming Call
    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null){
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    }
                }
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) { //here start song when start application
                if (mediaPlayer != null){
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null){
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    }
                }
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };

    TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (mgr != null){
        mgr.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it getting started by the code within this block?

```
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) { //here start song when start application
            if (mediaPlayer != null){
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        }
```

If so you probably just need to have a flag e.g.

```
private boolean mPlaying;
```

Set it to `true` when the music is manually started by the user then change the above block to something like:

```
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) { //here start song when start application
            if (mediaPlayer != null){
                if (mPlaying && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        }
```